ASP.NET Core 6 Identity calling login at startup not home page
I was quickly setting up a new website using an existing one that I'd build which uses ASP.NET Core Identity. The existing website loads the home page (/Index.cshtml), then a link on that page allows administrators to log in.
The copied website starts with Account/Manage/Login.cshtml, even though I have not added any code to call this. I've checked the routing and can see nothing to do this. The default UseMVC endpoint shows
{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}

I've tried adding <authentication mode="None"> to the web.config file.
As far as I can make out nothing has changed between the website that I copied and this one and yet the newer website always starts with login and not the home page.

This issue is not related to Route. We should check HomeController first.
[Authorize]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;

    public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }
    ...

Then we will now the issue caused by [Authorize] attribute.
If you want to Anonymous access the home page , we should use         [AllowAnonymous] attribute. Like below.
[Authorize]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;

    public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }
    // add this line
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
    ...

